# How to show data received from an Arduino device via Bluetooth in RealTime?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, arduino

So we have a device which calculates various parameters like Heart Rate, BP etc and we need it to communicate with our Android App in realtime. The Android app is a Cordova App with AngularJS as its frontend.

The frontend would have forms containing various fields like Heart Rate, BP etc.
While the device is measuring the parameters, it can send the data in realtime using Bluetooth. The problem lies in the Cordova app which has to capture the streaming data and show it on the UI in realtime.

How would I have to architect the whole process so that I can see the data in realtime on the AngularJS frontend?

Do I have to use Websockets to enable real time data between the UI and the backend? If so, who would I have to setup the Websocket integration? Or are there any others solutions for this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This seems to be a very broad question, different developers would have different approach.. You should be on point when you ask question in SO...

Comment: I just wanted to know whats the best approach, since I'm very new to this. Just wanted everyones opinions .Also what appraoch would you take? @AjayKulkarni

Comment: It is actually simple... You won't even need my approach. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/communicate-with-your-arduino-through-android/ or https://github.com/xseignard/cordovarduino or https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/communicate-with-your-arduino-through-android/ should help you

Comment: @AjayKulkarni This looks like its event based. What I meant was something like Web Sockets where I can stream data from the arduino to the Android App.

Comment: Try this... https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/8bitkick/sensor-data-streaming-with-arduino-683a6c

Comment: Somehow you find your way here to ask this while with less amount of effort you could have done those google searches yourself. I bet this is what the others did before they responded.